# Comparing Objects saved in ArrayList using "Boolean equals()"

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean, equals

I've a `Class` called `Products`. This class has a `name` and a `price`.
I can create a product the following way:

```
Product book = new Product();
book.setName("book");
book.setPrice(3);
```

After that I'm supposed check if this product already exists in the `ArrayList` I'm supposed to save it to and if it doesn't, then I just put it there. I'm supposed to do this using the following:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){

}
```

The problem is, how am I supposed to do it, if the `ArrayList` I'm supposed to save the product in, is created and initialised in the `public static void main` while this `boolean` is created before the `ArrayList` even exists?

Should I just make the `Class` itself an `ArrayList`, like so?

```
public class ArrayList<Product>{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boolean is not created before your ArrayList exists.

You need to overwrite the equals() method of Product like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == this) return true; // Both objects have the same reference -> the objects are equal
    if((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass())) return false; // Classes are different -> objects are different
    Product p = (Product) obj; // Cast obj into Product
    if( (this.getPrice() == p.getPrice()) && (this.getName().equals(p.getName())) ) return true; // Price and name are the same -> both products are the same
    return false; // At this point the two objects can't be equal
}
```

This is how you create an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

And this is how you add a Product when it doesn't exist in the list:

```
    if(!products.contains(yourProduct)){ // Checks if yourProduct is not contained in products
        products.add(yourProduct); // adds yourProduct to products
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to write this. The explanation using comments on each line really helped me understand. :3

Comment: Note that you should check for `obj == null` before calling `obj.getClass()`, to avoid a NullPointerException. You also often put in a check for `obj == this` as the very first check, as an object should be equal to itself, and this is a much lighter weight thing to check than the rest of the method.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for noting that, I forgot about that. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about it's existence. Since you are overiding equals method in your Product class, You can try doing this below

```
if(yourArayList.contains(book)){
   // it existed in the list
 }else{
   yourArayList.add(book);
}
```

When you call the contains method it internally calls the equals method of Product method vs the object being passed to it.

Comment: A bit short on the explaining, but thank you nonetheless. :3

Answer (score 1):

> this `boolean` is created before the `ArrayList` even exists?

You misunderstood the way `equals` works. It does not "create" a `boolean` until you call it with some object as an argument, and it returns a `boolean` based on the attributes of the object that you pass.

When you define your `equals` method you provide code to decide equality, but you are not deciding anything at that moment:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (obj == this) return true
    if (!(obj instanceof Product)) return false;
    Product other = (Product)obj;
    if (!other.getName().equals(getName())) return false;
    if (!other.getPrice() == getPrice()) return false;
    return true;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31*getName().hashCode() + getPrice();
}
```

Now you can use `equals` to deicide if a list has your `Product` in one of two ways:

- Use `contains` - this method calls `equals` to check containment, or
- Iterate all objects, and call `equals` manually.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the explanation. :3

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create your own ArrayList class.
If you implement you equals right, it will be called to check if you have it in the list when you execute `myList.contains(book)`

Actually there is a structure that will let you skip performing the check in your code. You can use the `java.util.HashSet`. It ensures that no duplicates can be added. In addition it returns the boolean value saying if the element was added. E.g.

```
Set<Product> mySet = new HashSet<>(); 
boolean added = mySet.add(book);
```

Please don't forget the easy to follow rule - when defining the equals, define the hashCode too. If you use an IDE, you can generate them both easily.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using `HashSet` since I don't fully understand it yet, but I appreciate the help and time you took to write it. ^_^